# File does not exist in the sdcard/download folder

Tags: android

I am using the following code to download a file from a website. But when I go to the sdcard/download folder, the file does not exist.

```
if(et1.equals(example)){

                try {
                    //this is the file you want to download from the remote server
                    String path ="http://lifecraze.com/sercice_tax_faq.zip";
                    //this is the name of the local file you will create
                    String targetFileName = "sercice_tax_faq.zip";
                        boolean eof = false;
                    URL u = new URL(path);
                    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    c.setDoOutput(true);
                    c.connect();
                    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("sdcard/download/"+targetFileName));
                        InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int len1 = 0;
                        while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                        f.write(buffer,0, len1);
                                 }
                    f.close();
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent it=new Intent(Example.this,Sucess.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }
            else{
                Intent it=new Intent(Example.this,Failed.class);
                startActivity(it);
            }
        }
    });
```

Please help me how to get the file in the sdcard/download folder.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: This is a very old post. But just in case, if some one faces the same issue. one possible cause or most common cause why the listFiles in the above code might return nothing is, if you don't have a permission for read external storage in your manifest file. I wasted lot of time, not knowing what I am doing wrong. Thought might help some one.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

`new File("sdcard/download/"+targetFileName));`

Try:

`new File("/sdcard/download", targetFileName));`

Notice the leading slash. You wanted an absolute path.

But, this is better because then we don't make assumptions on where the sdcard is mounted.

`new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString(), targetFileName);`

Comment: Thank you but still the file is not there in the sdcard/download folder

Comment: @SanchitKalra, if your file is not being created your `FileOutputStream` line is not being ran. Take a look at your network code and make sure it isn't blocking forever.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise using the method `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()` to ensure that you're getting the correct path to your mounted SD.

Your:

`FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("sdcard/download/"+targetFileName));`

becomes

`FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+targetFileName));`